# Change background color of property hint on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor

[image: Code example]

When I click on the property "cookie", VS automatically highlights wherever the property is used.

How do I change the color from gray to something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
TOOLS -> Options -> Font & Colors -> Highlighted Reference
```